# How to change particular value from paragraph if value is repeated

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, sed

Working on SUSE machine.

This is one paragraph from my file

```
<object class="SaImmMngt">
                <dn>safRdn=immManagement,safApp=safImmService</dn>
                <attr>
                        <name>saImmRepositoryInit</name>
                        <value>2</value>
                </attr>
     </attr>
    </object>
    <object class="SaLogStreamConfig">
            <dn>safLgStrCfg=saLogAlarm,safApp=safLogService</dn>
```

where "safRdn=immManagement,safApp=safImmService" is unique. I have to change the value 2 to 1 but these lines are repeated every where in file except unique line. I don't want to change it by line number.

I am trying this:

```
`sed -n '/safRdn=immManagement,safApp=safImmService/,/safLgStrCfg=saLogAlarm,safApp=safLogService/p' /etc/opensaf/imm.xml | sed -i '0,/1/s//2/' /etc/opensaf/imm.xml`
```

But this command will change the value everywhere, so how to catch that particular string and change in file.

Note: string 
"safRdn=immManagement,safApp=safImmService" is unique string in file while other lines are repeated everywhere in file. I don't want to create any extra file the changes should be in file only.

Comment: That's not a "paragraph" in a "file", that's (poorly indented/formatted) XML. Use an appropriate XML tool for the job, not a line-oriented stream editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed '/<object class="SaImmMngt">/,\#</object># {
   \#<dn>safRdn=immManagement,safApp=safImmService</dn>#,\#</object># { 
      \#<name>saImmRepositoryInit</name>#,\#</attr># {
         \#<value># s/2/1/
         }
      }
   }' YourFile
```

- change the value in sub tree you selected using sub selection to only change section that correspond to your criteria.
- this could be shorter for specific known file, here this is generic (reusable for other criteria)
- be carreful to pattern delimiter used (mainly `#` here, it can not be part of the pattern (like the default `/` unless you escape it)

Comment: Ok.. I got it, just I need to use it with -i, This solution is very useful

Answer (score 0):

This will change the value from 2 to 1 but only if it is within three lines after your unique string:

```
$ sed '/safRdn=immManagement,safApp=safImmService/,+3 s/<value>2/<value>1/' file
<object class="SaImmMngt">
                <dn>safRdn=immManagement,safApp=safImmService</dn>
                <attr>
                        <name>saImmRepositoryInit</name>
                        <value>1</value>
                </attr>
     </attr>
    </object>
    <object class="SaLogStreamConfig">
            <dn>safLgStrCfg=saLogAlarm,safApp=safLogService</dn>
```

To change the file in place, use the `-i` option.

```
sed -i '/safRdn=immManagement,safApp=safImmService/,+3 s/<value>2/<value>1/' file
```

#### How it works

- `/safRdn=immManagement,safApp=safImmService/,+3`

  This sets a range that starts with the line containing your unique string and continues through the first three lines which follow.

  If, in general, three lines are not enough, you can increase the number to whatever you need.
- `s/<value>2/<value>1/`

  This command is only applied to lines within the range.  For any line within the range, the string `<value>2` is changed to `<value>1`.